# How to set delay in jcarousel between scoll?

Tags: jcarousel

I am using a circular jcarousel where items are moving backward and forward. I need to set a time delay before it scolls back to reverse direction. how can I do that?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it not possible? Nobody to answer the question?

Answer (score 4):

Please set time delay to auto.

```
$('#jcarousel').jcarousel({
  auto: 3, //delay 3 seconds
  wrap: 'circular',
  animation: 1000,
  scroll: 1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets check it:

```
$('.jcarousel')
    .jcarousel({
        // Core configuration goes here
    })
    .jcarouselAutoscroll({
        interval: 3000,
        target: '+=1',
        autostart: true
    })
;
```

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/reference/installation.html